# How to check for specific pattern in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I am parsing the Log file row by row,  and check if the row is defined with the correct pattern if it follows the pattern I am processing that row.
example:
inside Perl script

```
my $reg=  qr/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})\:\d{2}\sID:(.*?)\|RID:(.*?)\|M:(.*?)\|S:(.*?)\|AI:(.*?)\|AC:(.*?)\|OH:(.*?)\|CLID:(.*?)\|FM:(.*?)\|TO:(.*?)\|EP:(.*?)\|CQ:(.*?)\|MN:(.*?)\|IN:(.*?)$/;
```

then I am doing this,

```
if($line =~ $reg){
                $YEAR   = $1;   $MONTH     = $2;        $DAY       = $3;        $HOUR      = $4;        $MIN    =$5; $S     = $9;   $ID       = $10;       $EP       = $16;
//Further logic
}
```

content of file is:

```
2021-02-16 11:05:14 ID:|RID:|M:|S:200|AI:10|AC:|OH:139644905692592|CLID:642208aa-cc6f-1239-8db7-fa163e46bd1e|FM:|TO:|EP:600000|CQ:|MN:|IN:
2021-02-16 11:05:14 ID:|RID:|M:|S:200|AI:10|AC:|OH:139644905692592|CLID:642208aa-cc6f-1239-8db7-fa163e46bd1e|FM:|TO:|EP:600000|CQ:|MN:|IN:
```

For this everything is working fine..

But when I changed the sample input file i.e added one more number hereafter time,`2021-02-16 11:05:14,450 ID:` , pattern is not matching, I am not getting how to add the pattern for ,

Updated input LOG file contains:

```
2021-02-16 11:05:14,450 ID:|RID:|M:|S:200|AI:10|AC:|OH:139644905692592|CLID:642208aa-cc6f-1239-8db7-fa163e46bd1e|FM:|TO:|EP:600000|CQ:|MN:|IN:
```

what to add to my pattern to match `11:05:14,450`,

I tried below but its not working:

```
my $reg=  qr/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})\:\d{2}\,(.*?)\sID:(.*?)\|RID:(.*?)\|M:(.*?)\|S:(.*?)\|AI:(.*?)\|AC:(.*?)\|OH:(.*?)\|CLID:(.*?)\|FM:(.*?)\|TO:(.*?)\|EP:(.*?)\|CQ:(.*?)\|MN:(.*?)\|IN:(.*?)$/;
```

Comment: Append `(?:,.+?)?` just after `:\d{2}` which corresponds with the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Change `\,(.*?)` to `(,\d+)?`. Example code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "2021-02-16 11:05:14,450 ID:|RID:|M:|S:200|AI:10|AC:|OH:139644905692592|CLID:642208aa-cc6f-1239-8db7-fa163e46bd1e|FM:|TO:|EP:600000|CQ:|MN:|IN:";
my $reg=  qr{^(?<year>\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})\:\d{2}(,\d+)?\sID:(.*?)\|RID:(.*?)\|M:(.*?)\|S:(.*?)\|AI:(.*?)\|AC:(.*?)\|OH:(.*?)\|CLID:(.*?)\|FM:(.*?)\|TO:(.*?)\|EP:(.*?)\|CQ:(.*?)\|MN:(.*?)\|IN:(.*?)$};

if($line =~ $reg){
    print "YEAR: ", $+{year}, "\n";
}
```

Note that I have also used [regexp named captures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre), I think they are useful in this case (if your Perl is >= 5.10).